# For loop takes the the max count

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

```
 private List<SurveyDetail> GetSurveyDetails()
    {
        List<SurveyDetail> surveyDetails = new List<SurveyDetail>();
        SurveyDetail detail = new SurveyDetail();
        int cid = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
           detail.choiceId = "1";
           detail.choiceDesc = "tesT";
           detail.questionId = i.ToString();
           surveyDetails.Add(detail);
        }
        return surveyDetails;
    }


 public class SurveyDetail
    {
        public string questionId { get; set; }
        public string choiceId { get; set; }
        public string choiceDesc { get; set; }
    }
```

when I run the code it question Id always gives me the last number of i that was run for example, in this case, it gives me 2. It gives me 2 on both counts.
Where I want the questionid to be 1 in the first count and 2 in the second.

Comment: You add the same instance of `detail` to the list twice. Hence it has same id. And all other properties.

Comment: In addition to GSergs comment, you need to instantiate a `new SurveyDetail()` in every iteration of the loop, otherwise you're just modifying the same instance over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move `SurveyDetail` initialization into the `for` body

```
private List<SurveyDetail> GetSurveyDetails()
{
    List<SurveyDetail> surveyDetails = new List<SurveyDetail>();
    int cid = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        SurveyDetail detail = new SurveyDetail();//<==NOTE THIS
        detail.choiceId = "1";
        detail.choiceDesc = "tesT";
        detail.questionId = i.ToString();
        surveyDetails.Add(detail);
    }
    return surveyDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase you want to use : LINQ

```
 var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(detail => new SurveyDetail
        {
            choiceId = "1",
            questionId = detail.ToString(),
            choiceDesc = "testT",
        });
```